# Android Studio (java): Image from array to PDF using iText

Tags: java, image, android-studio, itext, pdf-generation

Currently the user selects their images within a fragment and it converts them into an array with a string path name. I want to put that image on the PDF, but there is a formatting issue. I am trying to use the code below to fix that. Currently everything checks through until the cursor.MoveToFirst() returns null.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= imgArray.size(); i++) {

            Uri selectedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(imgArray.get(i)));
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

           Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst(); //ERROR: NULL

           int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

            Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
            doc.add(image);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** I figured this out. This seems to work for me! Use bitmap configurations.

for (int i = 0; i < imgArray.size(); i++) {

```
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgArray.get(i));
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);


            Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
            doc.add(image);


        }
```